# Is there a pattern for rendering a third party object as a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Image that I have a class that is provided by some third party gem like the one that follows.

```
class ThirdPartyThing
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def to_s
    @name.to_s
  end
end
```

Suppose I want to implement my own way to render the object as a string. I know of three options that I can take here:

1. Reopen the `ThirdPartyThing` class and override the to_s function.
2. Reopen the `ThirdPartyThing` class and define a new function.
3. Define a seperate function which takes `ThirdPartyThing` as an argument e.g.

   ```
   def third_party_thing_to_s(third_party_thing)
     third_party_thing.to_s.capitalize
   end
   ```

There maybe other options that I am not considering.

My question is "Is there a pattern for rendering a third party object as a string in ruby?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with 3. - `Define a seperate function which takes ThirdPartyThing`. Why not 1. or 2.?

> 1. Reopen the ThirdPartyThing class and override the to_s function:

If other code uses the `to_s` function it may have undesired results in this code. Other code may expect `to_s` to behave in the original way, maybe even `ThirdPartyThing` by itself.

> 2. Reopen the ThirdPartyThing class and define a new function:

Works until a new version of `ThirdPartyThing` introduces a method with the same name as your monkey patched (then you override it and bad stuff happens). Not so likely but might still happen, even with very weird method names! (And you know Moore's law...).

Generally, I'd try to not modify third party libraries.

You could write a general method, too:

```
def my_special_to_s(object)
  if object.is_a?(ThirdPartyThing)
      object.to_s.capitalize
  elif object.is_a?(SomeOtherThingYouWantSpecialToS)
      object.do_fancy_to_s
  else
      # use the default to_s
      object.to_s
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also 4, write a decorator which wraps ThirdPartyThing and provides the required functionality. This is basically option 3, but in a more OO wrapper.

```
class ThirdPartyThingDecorator
  def initialize(thing)
    @thing = thing
  end

  def to_s
    # Something that renders @thing as a string here
  end    
end

ThirdPartyThingDecorator.new(my_thing).to_s
```

This is overkill for a single method such as to_s, but if you end up needing lots of presentational behavior, it's a great option, since you can encapsulate all your ThirdPartyThing-related behaviors in the same place.